# Filter objects by className from nodeList

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname, nodelist

I've got a nodelist of objects returned by a call to `document.getElementsByClassName('a')`. Some of these objects have an extra class *b*. How can I create an array of elements that contain both classes? I don't was use a global search for *b*. I prefer vanillaJS/ES6 code.

HTML code example:

```
<div class ="a"></div>
<div class ="a"></div>
<div class ="a b"></div>
<div class ="a"></div>
<div class ="a b"></div>
<div class ="a"></div>
```

Comment: Your question is a little ambiguous. Do you want a result that has elements of both classes, or do you want a result that only has elements with both classes.

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't specific. Clearly I want class 'a' nodelist index of objects containing 'b' class.

Comment: Clearly? I'm still confused. How about showing what the result should be?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try querySelector instead.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.a.b');
```

This is likely your simplest solution.

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't allow me to take indexOf this element from class 'a' list

Comment: @ClassicError: What does that have to do with your question? What are you *actually* trying to do?

Answer (score 9):

The documentation for [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) states it can accept a string with multiple class names (separated by a space):

> ```
>  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(names); // or:
>  var elements = rootElement.getElementsByClassName(names);
> ```
>
> - *elements* is a live [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) of found elements.
> - *names* is a string representing the list of class names to match; class names are separated by whitespace

and also in the **Examples** section:

> Get all elements that have both the 'red' and 'test' classes:

> ```
> document.getElementsByClassName('red test')
> ```

That function can be used for both class names. Generally using `querySelectorAll()` can be slower than using `getElementsByClassName()` for a simple selector with class names. See comparison in [this jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/selectingmultipleclassesgetelementsvsqueryselectorall) . Related: [querySelector and querySelectorAll vs getElementsByClassName and getElementById in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14377614/1575353)

```js
const abElements = document.getElementsByClassName('a b');
console.log(abElements);
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a b"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a b"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
```

---

If you have an existing collection from [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) with only the elements that have class name `a` then the [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method can be used to keep only the elements that have the second class, utilizing [`Element.classList.contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Methods) to only include elements with both class names. See a demonstration below. Because `document.getElementsByClassName()` returns a returns a live [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList) you will need to put the elements into an array before you can call that filter method.

#### ES-6 Version

The [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) can be used to put the elements into an array before calling the filter method.

```js
const aElements = document.getElementsByClassName('a');
const abElements = [...aElements].filter(element => element.classList.contains('b'));
console.log(abElements);
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a b"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a b"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
```

#### ES-5 Version

Note that [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) has limited browser support (e.g. not in IE 9-) so in order to check for the *b* class without using that property, you could split the class names (using property *className*) into an array and use [Array.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```js
var aElements = document.getElementsByClassName('a');
var abElements = Array.prototype.filter.call(aElements, function(element, index, aElements) {
  var classNames = element.className.split(' ');
  return classNames.indexOf('b') > -1;
});
console.log(abElements);
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a b"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a b"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
```