# What is the difference between querySelectorAll() and getElementsByClassName()

Tags: javascript, dom

Apparently these two functions are similar, which is more performative? Which one should I use? What's the difference between the two?

***document.querySelectorAll()***

```js
function funDOM() {
    var x = document.querySelectorAll(".example");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body onload="funDOM()">
    <div>
        Doubts <span class="example">red</span>
    
    </div>
    <p class="example">red</p>
    
    
</body>
</html>
```

***document.getElementsByClassName()***

```js
function funDOM() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("example");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body onload="funDOM()">
    <div>
        Doubts <span class="example">red</span>
    
    </div>
    <p class="example">red</p>
    
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14377590/queryselector-and-queryselectorall-vs-getelementsbyclassname-and-getelementbyid answer your question?

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a live nodelist, `querySelectorAll` doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that `querySelectorAll` allows you to search for more than just classes. You can search with any CSS selector.

Realistically, there isn't much of a performance difference between the two, but if you only want to search by class name, you should use `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: there is one more important difference pointed out by Andy in his comment