# Sum numbers in html inputs, Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I am just learning to code, I am at the very beginning.
I am trying to code this calculator for my job, I have tried for days, and even researching, I just can't make it work. It's probably the simplest thing ever...I am just in te deepest forest regarding functions! I changed this code so many times I don't even know where I'm at. I'm a mess, help!

```js
function myF() {
  var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
  var b = document.getElementById("b").value;
  var c = document.getElementById("c").value;
  var d = document.getElementById("d").value;
  var e = document.getElementById("e").value;
  var f = document.getElementById("f").value;
  var g = document.getElementById("g").value;
  var h = document.getElementById("h").value;
  var i = document.getElementById("i").value;

  var tot = document.getElementById("result").value = a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i;
}
```

```css
body {
  background: url(img/Construction-Wallpaper-8.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

form {
  width: 530px;
  align-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: solid 1px darkslategrey;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  display: block;
}

input {
  float: right;
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
  top: -4;
}

label {
  padding: 8px 10px;
  font-family: "Gabriola Regular", arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: black;
  display: block;
}

input#result {
  position: relative;
  right: 18px;
  top: 6px;
}

button#Total {
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
  top: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, darkslategrey, white);
  font-family: "Gabriola Regular", arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

button#Total:active {
  position: relative;
  top: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button#Total:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

p#title {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px 0 0 0;
  font-family: "Gabriola Regular", arial, sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: bolder
}

img#Logo {
  width: 70px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 9px;
}

p#Logo {
  font-family: "Gabriola Regular", arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  right: 105px;
}
```

```html
<p id="title">&#8226; Payment Schedule &#8226;</p>
<div id="companyName">
  <p id="Logo">Christopher Crawford Const.
  </p>
  <img src="img/Logo_Crawford1ps.png" id="Logo">
</div>


<form>
  <label>I.Downpayment 5/14 <input id="a" type="text"></label>
  <label>II.Progress payment end of week2, @15% 5/30<input id="b" type="text"> </label>
  <label>III.Progress payment end of week4, @15% 6/13<input id="c" type="text"></label>
  <label>IV.Progress payment end of week6, @15% 6/27<input id="d" type="text"></label>
  <label>V.Progress payment end of week8, @15% 7/11<input id="e" type="text"></label>
  <label id="f">VI.Progress payment end of week10, @15% 7/25<input id="f" type="text"></label>
  <label>VII.Progress payment end of week11, @7.5% 8/1<input id="g" type="text"></label>
  <label>VIII.Progress payment end of week12, @7.5% 8/8<input id="h" type="text"></label>
  <label>IX.Final Payment @10%<input id="i" type="text"></label>
  <button id="Total" value="Add Numbers" onclick="myF()">Total</button>
  <input type="text" id="result">
</form>
```

Comment: What is the issue?  What specific problem are you having trouble with?

Comment: Instead of onclick, use onsubmit of the form and return false in the function. OR make the button `type="button"` - Also look at parseInt before concatenating the values

Comment: `document.querySelector("form").onsubmit=myF; ` and add `return false;` to the myF function at the end

Comment: I would suggest you to change the function `document.getElementById("a")` to `document.getElementsByClassName('sum')` which is going to return a list of all elements with that classname (`sum`). Plus, add the classname  `sum` to all your inputs.

Comment: Careful, there's a label with `id="f"`! You should not use same ID more than once (it's used for the input too). If you want to link a label to the input, use the `for="f"` attribute on label, instead of ID.

Comment: @GabrielHeming - better would be `document.querySelectorAll(".sum")`

Comment: @mplungjan is there a problem with "live node" or I missed something? BTW, thanks for the tip.

Comment: @mplungjan are you sure? https://stackoverflow.com/a/26757629/4944774 seems like querySelectorAll is a more expensive method?

Comment: You are concating strings not numbers.

Comment: @FabioLolli & GabrielHeming interesting that the querySelectorAll is not live. I did not know that. I only use it immediately and have never needed to update the DOM it was pointing at and then reuse the collection.

Comment: Thanks everybody, you were all useful. I managed to make it work! This was a big step for me! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you may have is that the value return strings and if you use `+` it will concatenate them, in order to have sum you need to parse the strings.

You can use trick like `+document.getElementById("a").value` or parseInt. If the value is float use parseFloat.

```
function myF() {
  var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("a").value);
  var b = parseInt(document.getElementById("b").value);
  var c = parseInt(document.getElementById("c").value);
  var d = parseInt(document.getElementById("d").value);
  var e = parseInt(document.getElementById("e").value);
  var f = parseInt(document.getElementById("f").value);
  var g = parseInt(document.getElementById("g").value);
  var h = parseInt(document.getElementById("h").value);
  var i = parseInt(document.getElementById("i").value);

  var tot = document.getElementById("result").value = a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to coding!

A few things:

1) Your form is submitting (and refreshing the page which loses input data) when you click total. Button elements are a type of "submit" by default. Change the property by adding `type="button"` to your button. Alternatively, you can also use onsubmit for the action on the form but be sure to use `e.preventDefault`. With onsubmit, don’t add `type="button"`, onsubmit needs the button type to be submit.

2) You have two `"F"` ids. On your "VI." label, remove `id="f"`. Remember, ids must be unique within the HTML document.

3) You will likely want to validate your input fields, since you only want numbers.

Comment: I suggest adding an expanation for #2.  Something along the lines of "IDs must be unique" or somesuch.

Answer (score 2):

### Adding Strings vs Integers

When you pull a value from an input with Javascript it is assumed to be a text, or string, value. Even if the text is numeric visually Javascript is going to attempt to concatenate them together as a string.

`a = '1', b = '2', c = a+b` where `c` is now `12` instead of `3`.

What you can do to avoid this is use `parseInt(val)`. `parseInt` takes a string input and returns the numeric value of it. If it cannot convert the input to a number it will return `NaN` or Not a Number.

Your `document.getElementById('id').value` lines should become `parseInt(document.getElementById('id'))` or when you go to add them together at the end use `parseInt` on your variables: `parseInt(a) + parseInt(b)`.

### Stoping the Form from Submitting

As other's have mentioned in comments your form is being submitted and taking you to a new page. You can prevent this, like they said, by changing the `type` on your button to `button`, `<button type="button" onclick="myF()">`. Alternatively you can prevent the default submit action with Javascript:

`document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', myF);`

And change your `myF` declaration to

```
function myF(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Stops the default action for the event from firing
  ..
```

When assigning a function to an event listener an event parameter is automatically passed in to the function. This is where `event` comes from even though we didn't specify it in `addEventListener`.

### IDs

In HTML an ID must be unique. You have two `f` IDs in your example. If you want to bind a label to an input you can use `<label for="id">` in this case `<label for="f">`. If you want to group elements that are similar in style/display use a class. Classes can be applied as many elements on a page.

### Don't Repeat Yourself

Is a pretty common practice. Why type `document.getElementById(..)` 10 times if you don't have to? Assign your inputs you want to sum together a class. If you want a more complex solution follow [Yosvel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50373933/4434366). I'll be taking a bit simpler approach.

```
var toAdd = document.querySelectorAll('.to-add');
var total = 0;
toAdd.forEach(function(input) {
  if ( !Number.isNaN(input.value) ) {
    total += input.value;
  }
});
```

[querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) takes in a selector and returns **all** elements that match. In our case we want all inputs with the class `to-add`. `querySelectorAll` returns an [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) which we can use as an array to loop over with `forEach`. On each itteration of the loop we check if the input's value is valid (`!Number.isNaN`) and if it is we add it to our total value.

```js
document.querySelector('#myForm').addEventListener('submit', myF);

function myF(event) {

  event.preventDefault();

  var toAdd = document.querySelectorAll('.to-add');
  var total = 0;

  toAdd.forEach(function(input) {

    if (!Number.isNaN(input.value)) {
      total += Number(input.value);
    }

  });

  document.getElementById('result').value = total;

}
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <label>I.Downpayment 5/14 <input class="to-add" type="text"></label>
  <label>II.Progress payment end of week2, @15% 5/30<input class="to-add" type="text" pattern="(\d+)"> </label>
  <label>III.Progress payment end of week4, @15% 6/13<input class="to-add" type="text"></label>
  <label>IV.Progress payment end of week6, @15% 6/27<input class="to-add" type="text"></label>
  <label>V.Progress payment end of week8, @15% 7/11<input class="to-add" type="text"></label>
  <label>VI.Progress payment end of week10, @15% 7/25<input class="to-add" type="text"></label>
  <label>VII.Progress payment end of week11, @7.5% 8/1<input class="to-add" type="text"></label>
  <label>VIII.Progress payment end of week12, @7.5% 8/8<input class="to-add" type="text"></label>
  <label>IX.Final Payment @10%<input class="to-add" type="text"></label>
  <button id="Total" type="submit" value="Add Numbers">Total</button>
  <input type="text" id="result">
</form>
```

```js
document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', myF);

function myF(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("a").value);
  var b = parseInt(document.getElementById("b").value);
  var c = parseInt(document.getElementById("c").value);
  var d = parseInt(document.getElementById("d").value);
  var e = parseInt(document.getElementById("e").value);
  var f = parseInt(document.getElementById("f").value);
  var g = parseInt(document.getElementById("g").value);
  var h = parseInt(document.getElementById("h").value);
  var i = parseInt(document.getElementById("i").value);

  var tot = document.getElementById("result").value = a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i;
}
```

```css
body {
  background: url(img/Construction-Wallpaper-8.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

form {
  width: 530px;
  align-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: solid 1px darkslategrey;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  display: block;
}

input {
  float: right;
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
  top: -4;
}

label {
  padding: 8px 10px;
  font-family: "Gabriola Regular", arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: black;
  display: block;
}

input#result {
  position: relative;
  right: 18px;
  top: 6px;
}

button#Total {
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
  top: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, darkslategrey, white);
  font-family: "Gabriola Regular", arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

button#Total:active {
  position: relative;
  top: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button#Total:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

p#title {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px 0 0 0;
  font-family: "Gabriola Regular", arial, sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: bolder
}

img#Logo {
  width: 70px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 9px;
}

p#Logo {
  font-family: "Gabriola Regular", arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  right: 105px;
}
```

```html
<p id="title">&#8226; Payment Schedule &#8226;</p>
<div id="companyName">
  <p id="Logo">Christopher Crawford Const.
  </p>
  <img src="img/Logo_Crawford1ps.png" id="Logo">
</div>


<form id="myForm">
  <label>I.Downpayment 5/14 <input id="a" type="number"></label>
  <label>II.Progress payment end of week2, @15% 5/30<input id="b" type="text" pattern="(\d+)"> </label>
  <label>III.Progress payment end of week4, @15% 6/13<input id="c" type="text"></label>
  <label>IV.Progress payment end of week6, @15% 6/27<input id="d" type="text"></label>
  <label>V.Progress payment end of week8, @15% 7/11<input id="e" type="text"></label>
  <label>VI.Progress payment end of week10, @15% 7/25<input id="f" type="text"></label>
  <label>VII.Progress payment end of week11, @7.5% 8/1<input id="g" type="text"></label>
  <label>VIII.Progress payment end of week12, @7.5% 8/8<input id="h" type="text"></label>
  <label>IX.Final Payment @10%<input id="i" type="text"></label>
  <button id="Total" type="submit" value="Add Numbers">Total</button>
  <input type="text" id="result">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice that you have two elements with the same `id="f"`

Also I suggest a code refactor using [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to get the `result` and as all the inputs are strings, I have created some methods to check if it is a number.

Code:

```js
document.querySelector('#Total').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd','e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'];
  const getValue = id => !Number.isNaN(+document.querySelector('#' + id).value) 
    ? +document.querySelector('#' + id).value
    : 0;
  const result = arr.reduce((a, c) => a + getValue(c), 0);
  document.querySelector('#result').value = result;
})
```

```css
form {width: 530px;align-content: center;margin: 0 auto;border: solid 1px darkslategrey;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;display: block;}input {float: right;clear: both;position: relative;top: -4;}label {padding: 8px 10px;font-family: "Gabriola Regular", arial, sans-serif;font-size: 18px;font-weight: bolder;color: black;display: block;}input#result {position: relative;right: 18px;top: 6px;}button#Total {position: relative;left: 10px;top: 5px;background: linear-gradient(to right, darkslategrey, white);font-family: "Gabriola Regular", arial, sans-serif;font-size: 25px;width: 100px;height: 30;text-align: center;text-transform: uppercase;box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px;border: solid 1px black;}button#Total:active {position: relative;top: 6px;cursor: pointer;}button#Total:hover {cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<p id="title">&#8226; Payment Schedule &#8226;</p>

<form>
  <label>I.Downpayment 5/14 <input id="a" type="text"></label>
  <label>II.Progress payment end of week2, @15% 5/30<input id="b" type="text"> </label>
  <label>III.Progress payment end of week4, @15% 6/13<input id="c" type="text"></label>
  <label>IV.Progress payment end of week6, @15% 6/27<input id="d" type="text"></label>
  <label>V.Progress payment end of week8, @15% 7/11<input id="e" type="text"></label>
  <label>VI.Progress payment end of week10, @15% 7/25<input id="f" type="text"></label>
  <label>VII.Progress payment end of week11, @7.5% 8/1<input id="g" type="text"></label>
  <label>VIII.Progress payment end of week12, @7.5% 8/8<input id="h" type="text"></label>
  <label>IX.Final Payment @10%<input id="i" type="text"></label>
  <button id="Total" value="Add Numbers">Total</button>
  <input type="text" id="result">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import your script file (the file that contains your javascript function "myF" to your html landing page like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

put this line in your inside head tags

your html need look like this:

```
<form>
    <label >I.Downpayment 5/14 <input id="a" type="text"></label>
    <label >II.Progress payment end of week2, @15% 5/30<input id="b" type="text"> </label>
    <label >III.Progress payment end of week4, @15% 6/13<input id="c" type="text"></label>
    <label >IV.Progress payment end of week6, @15% 6/27<input id="d" type="text"></label>
    <label >V.Progress payment end of week8, @15% 7/11<input id="e" type="text"></label>
    <label >VI.Progress payment end of week10, @15% 7/25<input id="f" type="text"></label>
    <label >VII.Progress payment end of week11, @7.5% 8/1<input id="g" type="text"></label>
    <label >VIII.Progress payment end of week12, @7.5% 8/8<input id="h" type="text"></label>
    <label >IX.Final Payment @10%<input id="i" type="text"></label>        
    <button type="button" id="Total" onclick="myF()">Total</button>
    <input type="text" id="result">
</form>
```

and your javascript file looks like this:

```
function myF() {
    var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("a").value);
    var b = parseInt(document.getElementById("b").value);
    var c = parseInt(document.getElementById("c").value);
    var d = parseInt(document.getElementById("d").value);
    var e = parseInt(document.getElementById("e").value);
    var f = parseInt(document.getElementById("f").value);
    var g = parseInt(document.getElementById("g").value);
    var h = parseInt(document.getElementById("h").value);
    var i = parseInt(document.getElementById("i").value);
    var tot = a+b+c+d+e;
    document.getElementById("result").value = tot;
}
```

`parsetInt()` is a function that do the trick. This convert your "5" to 5.