# Get value from JS to CSS like a progress bar

Tags: javascript, css

I tried to create a progress bar of a new page Im developing (you can chart your fav songs based on your preference)

The value that gives the width is

`+Math.floor(finishSize*100/totalSize)+`

But I haven't been able to put that into CSS. Or at least put it into style="". I've been looking for a tutorial but nothing has worked for me.

Here is my JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/h78jp4qo/

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
// Get your progress bar element
let progressBar = document.getElementsByClassName('progressbar');
// update the style width
progressBar[0].style.width = Math.floor(finishSize*100/totalSize)+'%';
```

In your fiddle, **Math.floor(finishSize*100/totalSize)+'%'** is evaluating to zero, so the bar isn't showing, that's whole other issue, but you can add this at the end of your showImage function to see that it will update your progress bar:

```
// Get your progress bar element
let progressBar = document.getElementsByClassName('progressbar');
// update the style width
progressBar[0].style.width = Math.floor(finishSize * 100 / totalSize) + '%';
progressBar[0].style.width = '33%';
```

Comment: I put it in the code, but it doesn't change the width of progress bar

Comment: Post the section of code that you put and I'll help walk you through it.

Comment: @MauricioVilla change `let progressBar = document.getElementsByClassName('progressbar');` to `let progressBar = document.getElementsByClassName('progressbar')[0];`

Answer (score 0):

```
let progressbar = document.querySelector('.progressbar');
progressBar.style.width = Math.floor(finishSize*100/totalSize)+'%';
```

First of all you neet select what you want change, in this case the class progressbar, after you can use `element.style.width = SIZE`
to select a element you can use `querySelector` if you are sure that will get only the first element or `getElementByClassName` for get a array off elements

[Here a explain about js selector element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14377590/queryselector-and-queryselectorall-vs-getelementsbyclassname-and-getelementbyid)

[querySelector document](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp)

[getElementByClassName document](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp)