# How to capture data from div by click

Tags: javascript

I would like to capture data from selected div(ie. name of country) by click and put in span , additionaly i want to find some way to mark selected divs, but also unmark others div which were selected previously.

https://codepen.io/tatasek/pen/PoojNGL

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="div div__first"></div>
    <div class="div div__second"></div>
    <div class="div div__third"></div>

    <p>I have selected:<span class="selectedCountry"></span></p>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;;
}

.div{
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 3px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: skyblue;
    cursor: pointer;
}

p{
    margin-left: 10px;;
}
.active{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

**JS**

```
const countries = ['Lithuania', 'Latvia', 'Estonia'];
const divList = document.querySelectorAll('.div');

divList.forEach(function(div, index){
    div.textContent = countries[index];

})
```

Thanks for your time! 
Michal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on what you've done so far, I just added some event listeners to check for changes and add the selected items to the list.  Let me know if you need any further clarification.

```js
const countries = ['Lithuania', 'Latvia', 'Estonia'];
const divList = document.querySelectorAll('.div');

divList.forEach(function(div, index){
div.textContent = countries[index];
div.addEventListener('click', function(){
  divList.forEach(function(el, i) {
    el.classList.remove('active')
  })
  this.classList.toggle('active');
})

})



var choices = document.getElementsByTagName('div')

for(var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
  choices[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
     document.getElementsByClassName('selectedCountry')[0].innerText = 
document.getElementsByClassName('active')[0].innerText;



  })
}
```

```css
body{
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.div{
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: skyblue;
    cursor: pointer;
}

p{
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.active{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="div div__first"></div>
    <div class="div div__second"></div>
    <div class="div div__third"></div>

    <p>I have selected:<span class="selectedCountry"></span></p>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for yoru help mate i will review this code tomorrow cuz im a little bit exhausted and i will let u know

Comment: If you click on 'Run code snippet' you can see it in action without having to plug it in to your code.

Comment: Hey why did you put here attribute “i” in the bracekts? 

`
divList.forEach(function(el, i) {
    el.classList.remove('active')
  })
`

Comment: Hey, sorry, I just realized I had that in there. That isn't needed in this scenario.  It's generally used to track the index of the iteration.  I have a habit of adding it in case I ever need to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for (let i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName('div').length; i++) {
   document.getElementsByClassName('div')[i].addEventListener('click', appendToSpan, false);
}
function appendToSpan(e) {
   document.getElementsByClassName('selectedCountry')[0].innerText += e.target.innerText;
}
```

**Edit:**

Change to:

```
const countries = ['Lithuania', 'Latvia', 'Estonia'];
const divList = document.querySelectorAll('.div');

divList.forEach(function(div, index){
    div.textContent = countries[index];
    div.addEventListener('click', function() {
      this.classList.toggle('active');
      if (this.classList.contains('active')) {
         document.getElementsByClassName('selectedCountry')[0].classList.add(this.innerText);
      } else {
         document.getElementsByClassName('selectedCountry')[0].classList.remove(this.innerText);
      }
      let classes = document.getElementsByClassName('selectedCountry')[0].getAttribute('class').split(' ');
      document.getElementsByClassName('selectedCountry')[0].innerText = '';
      for (let i = 1; i < classes.length; i++) {
         document.getElementsByClassName('selectedCountry')[0].innerText += classes[i]
      }
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks, i works partaly ( it doesnt delete previously selected country and it is getting a little mess) but i will try to solve this problem. thanks btw do u have any solution for my second problem?

Comment: yes it has been tested in codepen-- works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I've used `addEventListener` on `click` event on each `div`. Also I've created `selected` variable which is an `array` and keeps selected items. On click I check if the selected value is in `selected` variable by `indexOf()` function which returns `-1` if there is not. Then I `push()` value to the array if it's not selected yet or delete it by `splice()` and `index` of value.
Array is printed by `join()` function which concats each value of array,

```js
const divList = document.querySelectorAll('.div');
const output = document.querySelector('.selectedCountry');
const countries = ['Lithuania', 'Latvia', 'Estonia'];
let selected = [];

divList.forEach((div, index) => {
    div.textContent = countries[index];
    div.addEventListener('click',()=> {
      var indexOfDiv = selected.indexOf(countries[index]);
      (indexOfDiv >= 0) 
        ? (selected.splice(indexOfDiv,1) && div.classList.remove('selected'))
        : (selected.push(div.textContent) && div.classList.add('selected'))
      output.textContent = selected.join(', ');
    });
});
```

```css
.div { border: 1px solid lightgray; margin: 0.5rem; padding: 0.25rem 0.4rem; }
.div.selected { border-color: lightgreen; }
```

```html
<div class="div div__first"></div>
<div class="div div__second"></div>
<div class="div div__third"></div>
<p>I have selected:<span class="selectedCountry"></span></p>
```

Comment: Thanks man this is it! Frankly it is a tricky solution lol i thought it would be something a little bit simpler :D

Answer (score 0):

```js
const countries = ['Lithuania', 'Latvia', 'Estonia'];
const divList = document.querySelectorAll('.div');
const selectedCountry = document.getElementsByClassName('selectedCountry')[0];

function clearSelection() {
  divList.forEach(function(div) {
    div.classList.remove('active');
  })
}

divList.forEach(function(div, index){
    div.textContent = countries[index];
    div.addEventListener('click', function() {
      clearSelection();
      this.classList.add('active');
      selectedCountry.innerText = document.getElementsByClassName('active')[0].innerText;
    })
})
```

```css
body{
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.div{
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: skyblue;
    cursor: pointer;
}

p{
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.active{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="div"></div>
    <div class="div"></div>
    <div class="div"></div>

    <p>I have selected:<span class="selectedCountry"></span></p>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey man this code is really good, its intuitive, but iam little bit puzzled. why did u use `getElementsByClassname('selectedCountry)[0]` instead of using `querySelector('.selectedCountry')` I think the second solution is even more easy to undesrtand than your. does it have any advantages over my solution? Thanks mate

Comment: @MichałSoja There are some differences ([read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14377590/queryselector-and-queryselectorall-vs-getelementsbyclassname-and-getelementbyid)) but in this case it is not important what function you are using