# document.getElementsByClassName(...) returns "... is not a function"

Tags: javascript

I just started learning Javascript today and decided to start with practical examples, for example a toggle function.

---

This is what I've been ended with so far:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("toggle").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if(this.classList.contains("toggled")) {
    this.classList.remove("toggled")
  }
  else {
    this.classList.add("toggled")
  }
})
```

However it returns the error: *document.getElementsByClassName(...).addEventListener is not a function*. I figure that I havn't *declared* the `function` *correctly*, but can't figure why. Here's a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/SimplyCius/pen/PoNBxMz).

It's probably less of a problem as what I see it.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` will give you an array of dom elements. So either you loop and bind the listener or take the certain index and it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with that is that, `document.getElementsByClassName()` returns array of DOM elements. To bind event to elements, you would have to iterate though each element, and bind event to it. Do it like this :

Convert the HTML collection before iterating :

```
[...document.getElementsByClassName("toggle")].forEach(function(item){
  item.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if(this.classList.contains("toggled")) {
      this.classList.remove("toggled")
    }
    else {
      this.classList.add("toggled")
    }
  })
});
```

**OR**

Using `querySelectorAll()` :

```
document.querySelectorAll(".toggle").forEach(function(item){
  item.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if(this.classList.contains("toggled")) {
      this.classList.remove("toggled")
    }
    else {
      this.classList.add("toggled")
    }
  })
});
```

**For detecting click on any element other than with class `toggle` :**

```
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function(event){
  if(!event.target.classList.contains('toggle'){
    //code to do
  }
});
```

Comment: I guess this is best in the sense of reusability of the element, I figured I could use a `for` loop as well, right?

Comment: Yes you can use any loop for that. Just make sure you bind event to the element individually.

Comment: Aight, thanks for the quick response. I'll accept your answer as soon as I can.

Comment: Happy coding :)

Comment: Not an array, an `HTMLCollection` (which doesn't have a `forEach` method). But you can convert to an array with `...spread` operator (`[...document.getElementsByClassName("toggle")].forEach(...)`)

Comment: @LionelRowe thank you for enlightening me. I was thinking of `querySelector()` which works fine.

Comment: @PranavRustagi. I have a question, expanding this topic, is it possible to detect a click anywhere on the viewport besides the element?

Comment: @Simplicius I have added code for that, in the end.

Comment: @PranavRustagi. Sleek. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The method `document.getElementsByClassName` (element**s**) returns an array of elements with this class. So when you want to access elements of the array you has to to something like:

```
let firstElement = document.getElementsByClassName("toggle")[0]
```

If you want to access exactly one element, use `document.getElementById` or `document.querySelector('.toggle')`

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the index of element. In your case 0

```
document.getElementsByClassName("toggle")[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
  if(this.classList.contains("toggled")) {
    this.classList.remove("toggled")
  }
  else {
    this.classList.add("toggled")
  }
})
```

Comment: Since you have only one element with className "toggle", its 0 (in your case). But one thing to remember is that except for Id selector, for all selectors (clas, tag etc.,) we must use index.

Comment: Yes, if there was a second, which I wanted to target id use `[1]`, since JS is `0` based, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

Please prefer `querySelectorAll` over `getElementsByClassName`.
In both cases you will give you an array of dom elements. So either you loop and bind the listener or take the certain index and it will work

```
const toggleButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".toggle")
if(toggleButton.length > 0) {
    toggleButtons[0].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
       if (this.classList.contains('toggled')) {
            this.classList.remove('toggled');
        } else {
            this.classList.add('toggled');
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: So the `if` statement is meant to check wether `.toggle` exists and only execute if this condition is met, right? But why prefer `querySelectorAll`?

Comment: yes, it is to check else it throws an exception. Because querySelectorAll() returns a list that is static from the moment it is called, its list of items cannot be updated thereafter even if changes are made to the DOM dynamically

Comment: Nice to know. Sorry if I ask too much, but why would I prefer this feature?

Comment: in your case, there is no measure difference considering `querySelectorAll `. But I would like to suggest to use `querySelectorAll` and `querySelector`. Here you don't need to remember all the other selectors and most of the dom operations can be done using these.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for you explanation!

Comment: You are welcome. I could not explain all the differences here in the comments, but there are many advantages using these. Consider visiting this link for more info. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14377590/queryselector-and-queryselectorall-vs-getelementsbyclassname-and-getelementbyid