# I automated a code that goes to google and logs in but the file i want to download its ID keeps changing

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

Im using selenium basic with vba to automate my code to go to google, sign in, sort by last updated and download file to excel now the issue is that the file's ID keeps on changing, is there a code to add to mine to make it click on the download file i need? even though the ID keeps changing?

````
    Dim bot As WebDriver
    Set bot = New WebDriver
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim txt As String, link As String
    bot.Start "chrome"
    bot.Get "sharepoint link"
    bot.FindElementById("UserName").SendKeys "user"
     bot.FindElementById("Password").SendKeys "pass"
     bot.FindElementById("btnSubmit").Click
     bot.FindElementById("lastupdated").Click
    bot.FindElementById("lastupdated").Click 
   bot.FindElementById("downloadExcel").Click (i want the download id here for the changing ID)
     
   Stop

End Sub```
````

Comment: Hey and welcome? Can you share the EXCEL file or the vba code, so we can review it?

Comment: yes ofcourse @KargWare

Comment: `Sub Google_search()

    Dim bot As WebDriver
    Set bot = New WebDriver
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim txt As String, link As String
    bot.Start "chrome"
    bot.Get "sharepoint link"
    bot.FindElementById("UserName").SendKeys "user"
     bot.FindElementById("Password").SendKeys "pass"
     bot.FindElementById("btnSubmit").Click
     bot.FindElementById("lastupdated").Click
    bot.FindElementById("lastupdated").Click 
   bot.FindElementById("downloadExcel").Click (i want the download id here for the changing ID)
     
   Stop

End Sub`
@KargWare

Comment: Does any part of the ID remain constant? Does it position either absolute or relative remain static? Sharing a relevant html section (not as an image) is also important.

Comment: @QHarr there is one thing that remains constant something i forgot it but its like this ud-ui-3425 if i inspect it again it would be like this ud-ui-67

Comment: `bot.FindElementByCss("[id^='ud-ui-']").click`   Though if there are numerous ids on the page that start with that same string you will need to expand the css selector with additional locators to narrow down to one; or index into returned webElements collection (using `bot.FindElementsByCss("[id^='ud-ui-']")(index....).click` )

Comment: @QHarr thank you so much but can you tell me more about this index i never coded css

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors    and with `bot.FindElementsByCss("[id^='ud-ui-']")`  << that returns a collection. The first would be item 1 (I think) so `bot.FindElementsByCss("[id^='ud-ui-']")(1)` , 2nd item in the collection would `bot.FindElementsByCss("[id^='ud-ui-']")(2)` See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14377590/queryselector-and-queryselectorall-vs-getelementsbyclassname-and-getelementbyid

Comment: @QHarr ill see how it goes and check the links you sent me thank you so much