# add/remove class on screen size changes

Tags: javascript, css, bulma, screen-size, removechild

I have a project using the Bulma CSS framework and raw Javascript. I need to remove the "is-pulled-right" class on mobile screen sizes, however only the first element responds to the script, and the others are ignored. What am I doing wrong?

```js
window.addEventListener("resize", function () {

    const classList = document.getElementById("isRight").classList
    
    if(window.innerWidth < 820) {   
        classList.remove("is-pulled-right")
    } 

    else{
        classList.add("is-pulled-right");
    }

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.3/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="section">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="columns">
      <div class="column is-two-fifths">
        <h3 id="isRight" class="subtitle is-3 is-pulled-right ">First Title:</h3>
      </div><!-- column left-->
      <div class="column">
        <p>"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"</p>
      </div><!-- column right -->
    </div><!-- columns -->
  </div><!-- container -->
  
</section>

<section class="section">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="columns">
      <div class="column is-two-fifths">
        <h3 id="isRight" class="subtitle is-3 is-pulled-right ">Second Title:</h3>
      </div><!-- column left-->
      <div class="column">
        <p>"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"</p>
      </div><!-- column right -->
    </div><!-- columns -->
  </div><!-- container -->
  
</section>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [querySelector and querySelectorAll vs getElementsByClassName and getElementById in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14377590/queryselector-and-queryselectorall-vs-getelementsbyclassname-and-getelementbyid)

Comment: You can't have more than one element with a given id, in this case `isRight`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - the `id ("isRight")` should be unic in `html`. you should use `class` instead of `id` .

---

2 - you can use `document.querySelectorAll(".is-pulled-right")` for select all element with `is-pulled-right` class instead of
`document.getElementById("isRight")`

```js
    const classList = document.querySelectorAll(".is-pulled-right")
    
window.addEventListener("resize", function () {

    if(window.innerWidth < 700) {   
        classList.forEach( item => {
        item.classList.remove("is-pulled-right")})
    } 
 
    else{
      console.log('more')
        classList.forEach( item => {
        item.classList.add("is-pulled-right")})
    }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.3/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="section">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="columns">
      <div class="column is-two-fifths">
        <h3 id="isRight" class="subtitle is-3 is-pulled-right ">First Title:</h3>
      </div><!-- column left-->
      <div class="column">
        <p>"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"</p>
      </div><!-- column right -->
    </div><!-- columns -->
  </div><!-- container -->
  
</section>

<section class="section">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="columns">
      <div class="column is-two-fifths">
        <h3 id="isRight" class="subtitle is-3 is-pulled-right ">Second Title:</h3>
      </div><!-- column left-->
      <div class="column">
        <p>"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"</p>
      </div><!-- column right -->
    </div><!-- columns -->
  </div><!-- container -->
  
</section>
```

Comment: That did it, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

the javascript file you can use eventlistener if u want to add more than 1 event on the window

```
const div = document.getElementById("isRight")

window.onresize = function(){
    if(window.innerWidth < 820) {   
        div.classList.remove("is-pulled-right")
    } else {
        div.classList.add("is-pulled-right");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its is bad practice having multiple duplicates ids. since they should be unique. That's why `document.getElementById(id);` only returns one element.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Please use `class` instead. And then with something like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

If there is no way removing the ids then something like this should do it:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#isRight')).map(e => e.classList).forEach(classlist => {
    // your classlist logic
})
```

Comment: I've taken the id="isRight" off and replaced the javascript with window.addEventListener("resize", function () {

 const subtitleList = querySelectorAll('subtitle');
 
 if(window.innerWidth < 820) { 
  subtitleList.remove("is-pulled-right")
 } 

 else{
  subtitleList.add("is-pulled-right");
 }

}); after this, the DevTools is telling me that querySelectorAll is not defined

Comment: `querySelectorAll` uses css selectors, therefore you need to add a `.`(dot) to say its a class. It would look like this: `querySelectorAll('.subtitle');`. This will return an array of elements instead of a single element. You would need to loop through each element and add/remove the class how you did before.