# Can you search a HTMLElement for a particular class?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Say I have a DOM model that has a collection of elements with class: `class_1` and I use `document.getElementsByClassName("class_1")` to get an `HTMLCollection` of these elements.

If I take the first element of the collection is it possible to use the `.getElementsByClassName("...")` function again to get a secondary `HTMLCollection` of all the `class_2` elements within the first element?

Comment: Yes...
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName

Comment: you mean getting children of the first `.class_1` element? it should be `let element = document.getElementsByClassName("class_1")[0]; let children = element.getElementsByClassName("class_2");`

Comment: You'll find [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) easier to manage. It returns a non-live nodelist rather than a live HTML collection.

Comment: @Andy What's the difference between a live and non-live nodelist?

Comment: @Connor: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14377590/queryselector-and-queryselectorall-vs-getelementsbyclassname-and-getelementbyid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, with [querySelector/querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) : Like so:

```
let allDivs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
let justThat = allDivs.querySelector('.subItemClass'); // null if not found
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can call `getElementsByClassName` on the document root, but you can also call it on any other element.

```js
const classOne = document.getElementsByClassName("class1");
const classTwo = classOne[0].getElementsByClassName("class2");
```