# It returns me [object HTMLCollection]

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

i am trying to replicate a login page and i want that when i click the button it displays the name that you have putted but it returns [object HTMLCollection]

I expected to display the name that you putted

```js
var nombre = document.getElementsByClassName("Nombre")

function entrar() {
  //borramos todo el contenido del html dentro del body
  document.body.innerHTML = "";

  //añadimos el nombre
  var Elemento = document.createElement("h1")
  Elemento.textContent = "bienvenido " + nombre;
  document.body.appendChild(Elemento)
}
```

```css
.contenedor {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.Login {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.Todo {
  display: block;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="Todo">
  <div class="Login">
    <h2>Nombre</h2>
    <input type="text" class="Nombre" id="Name">
  </div>
  <div class="contenedor">
    <h2 class="palabra">Contraseña</h2>
    <input type="password" id="Contraseña" class="Contraseña">
  </div>

  <button type="button" onclick=entrar()>Entrar</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Look carefully at what `getElementsByClassName(...)` returns.

Comment: And note the big red warning [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) about what you get back, as well.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, `getElementsByClassName()` reutrns a NodeList of elements, not a single one. You're currently trying to write the entire NodeList object to the DOM, which is why you see the `[object HTMLCollection]` output.

Secondly, you need to get the `value` property of the element and display that.

Also note that using `onclick`, and other event attributes in your HTML, is no longer good practice. You should use unobtrusive event handlers bound within the JS code instead. You can use the `addEventHandler()` method to do this.

Here's a working example with the above issues corrected:

```js
const nombre = document.querySelector(".Nombre");
const button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  //borramos todo el contenido del html dentro del body
  document.body.innerHTML = "";

  //añadimos el nombre
  var Elemento = document.createElement("h1")
  Elemento.textContent = "bienvenido " + nombre.value;
  document.body.appendChild(Elemento)
});
```

```css
.contenedor {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.Login {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.Todo {
  display: block;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="Todo">
  <div class="Login">
    <h2>Nombre</h2>
    <input type="text" class="Nombre" id="Name">
  </div>
  <div class="contenedor">
    <h2 class="palabra">Contraseña</h2>
    <input type="password" id="Contraseña" class="Contraseña">
  </div>

  <button type="button">Entrar</button>
</div>
```

For some more information about the differences between `getElementsByClassName()`, `getElementById()`, `querySelector()`, `querySelectorAll()`, etc.  see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14377590/519413).

Comment: rory i copied your code and paste it and there is an error that says                                                       Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
    at script.js:4:8

Comment: Does the `<button>` element exist in your local version? I just used the simplest selector available based on your HTML example from the question.

Comment: i have this in my local version   <button type="button" onclick=entrar()>Entrar</button>

Comment: In which case, make sure you're executing the JS *after* the page has fully loaded. The simplest way to do this is to put the `<script>` tag right before `</body>`, not in the `<head>`

Comment: tried it and didnt worked the error is in this line                                                                  Elemento.textContent = "bienvenido " + nombre.value;                                                       it says that on value

Comment: alr thank you Rory i am new and i learned something new so thank you

Comment: Here's what the full HTML should look like: https://jsfiddle.net/bdtugvcr/

Comment: i putted it all on the html document as you did and it worked but when i try it with the different documents it says that error

Comment: I'd suggest perhaps starting a new question containing all the code which produces the error, as there's something not in the right place. Without seeing the code it's almost impossible to diagnose

Answer (score 0):

The function `getElementsByClassName()` returns an ARRAY (it is "element***s***"), so you need to extract the first element from the result (`[0]`) and then get that HTML elements `.value`.

Code updated below.

```js
var nombre = document.getElementsByClassName("Nombre")[0]

function entrar() {
  //borramos todo el contenido del html dentro del body
  document.body.innerHTML = "";

  //añadimos el nombre
  var Elemento = document.createElement("h1")
  Elemento.textContent = "bienvenido " + nombre.value;
  document.body.appendChild(Elemento)
}
```

```css
.contenedor {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.Login {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.Todo {
  display: block;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="Todo">
  <div class="Login">
    <h2>Nombre</h2>
    <input type="text" class="Nombre" id="Name">
  </div>
  <div class="contenedor">
    <h2 class="palabra">Contraseña</h2>
    <input type="password" id="Contraseña" class="Contraseña">
  </div>

  <button type="button" onclick=entrar()>Entrar</button>
</div>
```

Comment: i tested here and it worked i tested outside and it said:                           
                                                                                                                  
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
    at entrar (script.js:9:49)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:22:48)

Comment: Then that means you are calling `SOMETHING.value` but the SOMETHING is undefined.  Figure out what SOMETHING is and why it is undefined.  Maybe the class names differ between what is in the HTML and what you are using in `getElementsByClassName()` ?

Comment: i declared the variable named nombre with the value of the content on the text box an then on the function i call to the value of nombre